# How to plot a horizontal stacked bar with annotations

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-transform

- I used the example for Discrete distribution as horizontal bar chart example on matplotlib [Discrete distribution as horizontal bar chart](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-horizontal-barchart-distribution-py) to create a chart showing share of the vote in Shropshire elections 2017.
- However, because I did not know how to manipulate the data I had to manually enter my data in the program which is clearly down to my own ignorance.
- I have the relevant data in a CSV file and can therefore load it as a dataframe.

  - The CSV has a row for each ward, of which there are 63 and columns for the % vote for each party (Tory, LD, Labour, Green, Indep) so 5 substantive columns.
- I wanted advice as to how to change the form of the data so it resembles the input for this chart.
- I am not sure what it is but seems possibly a dictionary type with key and value:

#### My data reads in part:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

category_names = ['Labour', 'LD', 'Indep', 'Green', 'Tory']
results = {'Abbey': [16, 56, 4,0, 24],
           'Albrighton': [0, 0, 32, 0, 68],
           'Alveley & Claverley': [0, 25, 0, 0, 75],
           'Bagley': [30, 30, 0, 0, 40],
           'Battlefield': [34, 0, 0, 9, 57],
           'Bayston Hill, Column & Sutton': [53, 4, 3, 7, 33],
           'Belle Vue': [43,28,0,5,24]}


# setup dataframe using the dict provided in the OP
df = pd.DataFrame(results, index=category_names)

# display(df)
        Abbey  Albrighton  Alveley & Claverley  Bagley  Battlefield  Bayston Hill, Column & Sutton  Belle Vue
Labour     16           0                    0      30           34                             53         43
LD         56           0                   25      30            0                              4         28
Indep       4          32                    0       0            0                              3          0
Green       0           0                    0       0            9                              7          5
Tory       24          68                   75      40           57                             33         24
```

- I am trying to get the data to be formatted like this directly from the csv file when entered as a pandas dataframe.
- Have tried the values method and the `to_dict` method and while they get data looking similar they are not quite correct.

  - I believe there is a need to divide the data into keys and values but that is where my knowledge hits its limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Both options us DataFrame `df` from the OP.
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with the parameter `stacked=True`

### Option 1: `'Party'` as the y-axis

#### Using `matplotlib` from version 3.4.2

- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html)

  - See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for additional details and examples with `.bar_label`.
- See the [matplotlib: Bar Label Demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html) page for additional formatting options.
- **Tested in `pandas 1.3.2`, `python 3.8`<sup>1.</sup>, and `matplotlib 3.4.2`<sup>1.</sup>**

  - <sup>1. Minimum version required</sup>
  - `labels = [f'{v.get_width():.0f}' if v.get_width() > 0 else '' for v in c ]` without using the assignment expression (`:=`)
- Use `.get_height()` for vertical bars.

```py
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True, cmap='tab10', figsize=(16, 10))

for c in ax.containers:

    # format the number of decimal places and replace 0 with an empty string
    labels = [f'{w:.0f}' if (w := v.get_width()) > 0 else '' for v in c ]
    
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center')
```

#### Using `matplotlib` before version 3.4.2

- Extract the `.patch` components in a loop, and then only plot annotations for values greater than 0.

```py
# plot 
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True, cmap='tab10', figsize=(16, 10))

# annotations:
for p in ax.patches:
    left, bottom, width, height = p.get_bbox().bounds
    if width > 0:
         ax.annotate(f'{width:0.0f}', xy=(left+width/2, bottom+height/2), ha='center', va='center')
```

[image]

### Option 2: `'Ward'` as the y-axis

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) to swap the `Index` and `Columns`

  - `'Ward'` will now be the index and `'Party'` will be the columns

```py
# transpose df from the OP so Party is the in the columns and Ward is the index
dft = df.T

# display(dft)
                               Labour  LD  Indep  Green  Tory
Abbey                              16  56      4      0    24
Albrighton                          0   0     32      0    68
Alveley & Claverley                 0  25      0      0    75
Bagley                             30  30      0      0    40
Battlefield                        34   0      0      9    57
Bayston Hill, Column & Sutton      53   4      3      7    33
Belle Vue                          43  28      0      5    24
```

#### Using `matplotlib` from version 3.4.2

```py
# plot
ax = df.T.plot.barh(stacked=True, figsize=(16, 10))

plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))

# annotations:
for c in ax.containers:
    
    # format the number of decimal places and replace 0 with an empty string
    labels = [f'{w:.0f}' if (w := v.get_width()) > 0 else '' for v in c ]
    
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center')
```

#### Using `matplotlib` before version 3.4.2

```py
# plot
ax = dft.plot.barh(stacked=True, figsize=(16, 10))

plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))

# annotations:
for p in ax.patches:
    left, bottom, width, height = p.get_bbox().bounds
    if width > 0:
         ax.annotate(f'{width:0.0f}', xy=(left+width/2, bottom+height/2), ha='center', va='center')
```

[image]